# GO Datastore connection reuse

Tags: database, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to GO and i need to reuse the datastore client in the entire application instead of creating it again and again for each API call. I have created a db package and in it Init i am storing client in  a global db variable to reuse it via a GetDB() function. But i am getting the below error

> PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.

Below is my db package code

```
package db

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

var db *datastore.Client

func init() {
    fmt.Println("INIT IN DB PACKAGE CALLED")
    db = CreateDataStoreClient()
}

//CreateDataStoreClient client object
func CreateDataStoreClient() *datastore.Client {
    serviceAccountFilePath := os.Getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH")
    gcpProjectID := os.Getenv("PROJECT_ID")
    // Create a datastore client.
    client, err := datastore.NewClient(context.Background(), gcpProjectID, option.WithServiceAccountFile(serviceAccountFilePath))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ERROR IN CONNECTING TO DATASTORE")
    }
    return client
}

//GetDB ...
func GetDB() *datastore.Client {
    return db
}
```

I am trying to use the db variable in the below controller `enter code here`

```
func (ctrl CloudController) GenerateAPIKey(c *gin.Context) {
    // get the data store client
    dsClient := db.GetDB()
    // Request
    //ctx := appengine.NewContext(c.Request)
    ctx := context.Background()
    music := &Music{
        apiKey: generateAPIKey(40),
    }
    key := datastore.IncompleteKey("Account", nil)
    if _, err := dsClient.Put(ctx, key, music); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"message": "error in generating api key"})
    }
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"apiKey": music.apiKey})
}
```

Comment: Try using appengine's context, `appengine.NewContext(r)` instead of `context.Background()`.

Comment: @abhink I am using it inside `Init function`so i dont have a request context available at that moment.

Comment: @VishalBisht the error you're getting doesn't seem like it has anything to do with db client reuse but more like you don't have enough permissions to use whatever service is returning that error, which is also something you don't state... So what is returning the error?

Comment: @mkopriva if i am returning `func GetDB() *datastore.Client {
    return db
}`  then it is giving PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions. But if i return `func GetDB() *datastore.Client {
 return CreateDataStoreClient()
 //return db
}
` then it is working fine

Comment: @VishalBisht but what is giving you the error? `GetDB` does not have an error return argument so it cannot return an error.

Comment: @mkopriva i am getting error when i use db variable to save data to datastore

Comment: Is `os.Getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH")` the same value in both cases?